# CSS Adjusting Element Widths (Having trouble)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple calculator and am having trouble formatting the different element boxes. I basically just need to have the items in the left column (serving, first food, second food) be in the left part of the middle of the page, and the comparison be on the right part of the middle of the page. I'm trying to adjust the margins, but it keeps messing with my elements. I'm relatively new to this, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

My code:

```css
  .side {
  margin: 30%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21; 
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;  
}
.sideone {
  margin: 20%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  position:relative;
  width: 33%;
}
.comparison {
  position:relative;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
}
.color-red{
color:red;
background:transparent}
.color-green{
color:green;
background:transparent}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=10px, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <label>
    Servings:
    <input type="number" id="numberOfStocks" value="1" min="0" />
  </label>
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    <div class="side">
      <h2>First Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
      <select class="selectStock">
        <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="sideone">
      <h2>Second Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
      <select class="selectStock">
        <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comparison">
    <h2>Comparison:</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
```

Actual functionality isn't working on the snippet, but it's not really relevant to the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: so do you want both boxes on the left with comparison on the right?

Comment: Basically yes, but I need everything to be censored in the middle of the page. Right now it's all on the left and I'm not sure how to change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do? (https://jsfiddle.net/l0ul0u/sohpntvp/)

```
.side, .sideone {
    border: 3px solid #73AD21; 
}
h2{
    display: inline-block;
}
.outer {
    display: flex;
}
.color-red{
    color:red;
    background:transparent}
.color-green{
    color:green;
    background:transparent}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! How would I be able to make all the elements centered in the middle, but keep things on the left/right?

Comment: Thank you so much! Edit- do you know how I can add CSS classes to the dropdown menu as well? I'd also like to format it above the boxes on the left

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you are setting just div element. Take a look in others elements inside it, you can solve hidden them inside div using the overflow element like:

> overflow: hidden;

for example:

```css
.side {
  margin: 30%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21; 
  width: 10%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
      <h2>First Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
      <select class="selectStock">
        <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
```

But this way will hide them. You could solve it also setting the size of elements which are inside of div, I think that could be better for your proposal.

Comment: That makes sense- can you explain what you did? It looks a bit weird in the snippet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I copied a snippet of your code and just added "overflow: hidden" in ".side" css class. haha. Well, you can solve it in many ways. But I would like to know what exactly are you try to doing ? seems that you are trying fit in small screens! If it is you can make different layouts per screen size. But if is just a normal screen and you want fill it out set also the components size.

Comment: Yeah, It is a little bit weird in the snippet but it was just to show you a possibility to fill it with take not so long modifications. In case of combobox, you should try set the size of combox either, you are putting big things in a small box then will leak out.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying